# How to forward non-www URLs to www URLs

Tags: ruby-on-rails, heroku, hosting

I've had an issue with Google Adsense not being able to access their config file (ads.txt) on my Rails site. I have put it in what I think is the correct folder (App -> Public).

In summary, this is the situation for which URLs work vs not:

- [webURL].co.uk/ads.txt (works)
- https://www.[webURL].co.uk/ads.txt (works)
- http://www.[webURL].co.uk/ads.txt (works)
- https://[webURL].co.uk/ads.txt (doesn't work - hangs)
- http://[webURL].co.uk/ads.txt (doesn't work - error - HTTP Status: 404 (not found)

So my guess is that Google is trying to reach ads.txt via a URL without a www (the two bottom of the list above).

A couple of other points:

- My Rails app is hosted on Heroku and I have a GoDaddy domain
- On Godaddy, I have domain forwarding already setup, and so [mysite].com gets forwarded to www.[mysite].com.

So my question - how do I get URLs which **don't** have 'www' in them, to redirect to the equivalent URL **with** 'www'?

Any ideas?

Thanks in advance!

Comment: Is the `www` thing a redirect or an alias? Does your "dubless" site have a proper A record?

Answer (score 0):

I resolved this by setting up Cloudflare and configuring some forwarding rules.

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Answer (score 0):

i did a redirection on my hosting service. A 301 redirection from "mywebsite.com" to "www.mywebsite.com"